# Rails JSONAPI-Resources shows last page link but page-count is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonapi-resources

I have a Rails 5.1 app using the jsonapi-resources gem. In the config I set:

```
config.top_level_links_include_pagination = true
config.top_level_meta_include_page_count = true
```

which results in the following output:

```
"meta": {
  "page-count": null
},
"links": {
  "first": "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/smth?page%5Bnumber%5D=1&page%5Bsize%5D=15",
  "next": "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/smth?page%5Bnumber%5D=2&page%5Bsize%5D=15",
  "last": "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/smth?page%5Bnumber%5D=9&page%5Bsize%5D=15"
}
```

Now, what puzzles me, is that it obviously knows that there are 9 pages (see last pagination link), but the page count in the meta section is empty.

Any ideas why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

config/initializers/json_api.rb

```
JSONAPI.configure do |config|
  config.default_paginator = :paged
  config.default_page_size = 15
  config.maximum_page_size = 30
  config.allow_sort = true
  config.allow_filter = true
  config.top_level_meta_include_record_count = true
  config.top_level_links_include_pagination = true
  config.top_level_meta_include_page_count = true
  config.resource_cache = Rails.cache
end
```

Comment: Could you please share your `config/initializers/json_api.rb` file ?

Comment: @XavierDelamotte Added the entire config.

Comment: and which version of the gem are you using ?

Comment: @XavierDelamotte `gem 'jsonapi-resources', '~> 0.9.0'`

Comment: It looks indeed like a bug. I think you should  try to extract to a minimal rails application that is demonstrating the problem, and raise an issue on the gem github project.